# Javascript onclick function in PHP $cOutput

Tags: php, onclick

Our Wordpress site has some PHP pulling special meta data from custom fields entered in the front-end interface for Pages. This is legacy code and I HAVE to work within it.

The PHP code in our template is using $cOutput to pull and place the URL and link name from the custom field.

This is the PHP code I have to work within

```
{
  $cOutput .= '<div class="couponWidget"><img class="widgetImage widget" src="' . $couponImage1[0] . '" />';
  $cOutput .= '<a class="bar" href="' . $couponLink1 . '">Redeem your coupon now!</a></div>';
}
```

Our marketing agency wants to track the clicks on this URL and has given us the following onclick Javascript

```
onclick="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Conversions', 'redeem']);"
```

I have tried all the tricks I know to get Javascript to work within PHP while working within this legacy code and they haven't worked.

I'd appreciate any feedback on getting this onclick javascript to work in this PHP. I've already pulled out all the hair I can afford to loose over this.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you considered jQuery?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/methods/gaJSApi_gaq#_gaq.push

Answer (score 0):

Ignore that, forgot you can't edit the legacy code. If you can use jQuery, you should be able to do something like

```
$('.couponWidget .bar').attr("onclick","_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Conversions', 'redeem']);");
```

---

It looks to me that you just need to have

```
$cOutput .= '<a onclick="_gaq.push([\'_trackEvent\', \'Conversions\', \'redeem\']);" class="bar" href="' . $couponLink1 . '">Redeem your coupon now!</a></div>';
```

so that the single quotes don't mess with PHP when it's being output. What else have you tried?

Comment: he cant mess with that :D

Comment: Thanks Carl Vitullo. The backslashes fixed it; I'd had the closing \ on the wrong side of the closing '. Love a nice simple solution.

Answer (score 0):

try jquery binding event or just javascript, do a window.onload and inside that query the button to be tracked and then bind the event, that SHOULD work, bye.